# How did Frenchie manage to cast out Valak from the Nun's body?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-conjuring-universe, the-nun

In climactic scene of *The Nun*, Valak possesses Sister Irene's body while trapping her in a star marked shape in the cellar. While The Nun is chock-holding Frenchie, he manages to grab the orb containing Jesus's blood, which Sister Irene is wearing & manages to cast out Valak, thus freeing Sister Irene for the time being.

What did he do that made Valak leave Sister Irene's body. The orb was still intact so he couldn't have had Jesus's blood on his hands to make Valak leave. The orb itself isn't effective as Sister Irene is possessed while wearing the orb.

So what did he do?

Answer (score 1):

Frenchie manages to grab the orb when Valak-possessed Sister Irene trying to strangle him, and rubbed a bit Christ's blood on Sister Irene's face.

- It is Christ's blood that frees Sister Irene.

Comment: But how did he manage to get Christ's blood. The orb is still intact no? Only when the orb's glass breaks Irene manages to hold it in her mouth

Comment: in the flash back scene of people binding valak in the first place it is shown that they open the orb and take some drops of blood and binds valak. So it can be opened without breaking the glass